# Which plugin is used for deploy application on AWS beanstalk cloud servers in jenkins. please suggest

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using jenkins and taking code from SCM (GIT) successfully. Now I want to deploy my application on AWS beanstalk cloud servers , so how I can achieve it and which plugin I should follow.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say from very short description what do you want to achieve, but there is exactly one plugin for AWS, so you should definitely look at it first: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin